# Error when running angularjs karma sample

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, angularjs-e2e

In the introtokarma app, I changed the karma-e2e-config.js file as follows:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath : '../',
      files : ['tests/e2e/**/*.js'],
      frameworks: ['ng-scenario'],
      autoWatch : false,
      browsers : ['Chrome'],
      singleRun : true,
      proxies : {
        '/': 'http://localhost:8000/'
      },
      junitReporter : {
        outputFile: 'test_out/e2e.xml',
        suite: 'e2e'
      }
  });
};
```

When running the code, I get the following output:

> C:\Project\introtokarma\config>karma start karma-e2e.conf.js
>   INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.1 server started at localhost:9877/
>   INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
>   WARN [launcher]: The path should not be quoted.
>   Normalized the path to C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
>   INFO [Chrome 28.0.1500 (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket id pfBNNRs-3wAdgT-QsheL
>   Chrome 28.0.1500 (Windows 7): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.207 secs / 0 secs)

Answer (score 26):

For karma v0.10.2 and latest angular-phonecat try next command:

`npm install -g karma-ng-scenario karma-junit-reporter`

Comment: I tried all of the other suggestions, and was missing karma-junit-reporter.

Comment: the important thing is: use the `-g` flag to install it globally instead of locally: `npm help install`

Comment: This helped! I wonder why this dependency is not mentioned in Angularjs tutorial. It's a step-by-step tutorial, I wonder why'd they oversee this clearly needed module.

Comment: this needs to be in tutorial for sure.
http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the files key array of the config block and add a frameworks key.

the files key looks like this:

```
files: [
    ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
    ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
    'test/e2e/**/*.js'
]
```

Remove the `ANGULAR_SCENARIO`, and `ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER` lines.

So, in the end, it just looks like this:

```
files: [
    'test/e2e/**/*.js'
]
```

Then add a framkeworks key with an array and one value of ng-scenario:

```
frameworks: ['ng-scenario']
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That did not work. Thanks for your quick reply though. I updated the post to work with introtokarma

Comment: I tried that, but now I'm getting: Error: No provider for "framework:ng-scenario"! (Resolving: framework:ng-scenario)

Comment: Adam - try npm install karma-ng-scenario and see if that helps

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me (including installing karma-ng-scenario).

Answer (score 1):

Besides installing the `karma-ng-scenario` node module as @rkshnsk said, I also had to add it to the plugins array:

```
  plugins : ['karma-ng-scenario'],
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be "test" instead of "tests" in

```
      files : ['tests/e2e/**/*.js'],
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. I switched to karma 0.8.7 and everything works now.